# Why can I only deploy approx. 3 smart contracts per minute with infura using Ropsten and Rinkeby

Tags: nodejs, ropsten, infura, rinkeby, truffle-hdwallet-provider

I have created a Dapp that is written in Solidity and compiled with Truffle on both Rinkeby and Ropsten. I have also created a frontend for batch file uploads and a backend for the actual deploying using Truffle-HD-Wallet on Infura. The backend is written in JavaScript for Node.JS using the Express library. I am running the backend on port 80 and the frontend on 8080.

The problem I have is that although the data is passed back to the server very quickly (seconds), the actual deployment of over 200 records is performed 6 transactions at a time and approx. 3 deployed contracts per minute.

For testing this is fine, but to use this in the real world and perhaps more relevant to create 2000 contracts on the fly that will take far too long. Is there a setting somewhere that I can change? Is the limitation with Infura, with the testnets or with some combination of factors?

The backend code is:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();

// enable middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.json());

// Enable all CORS requests 
app.use(cors());

const Web3 = require("web3");
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");

require('dotenv').config();
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC, process.env.INFURA_URL);

var contract    = require("@truffle/contract");

const insurerArtifacts = require('./build/contracts/Insurer.json');
var insurerContract = contract(insurerArtifacts);
insurerContract.setProvider(provider);

const platformArtifacts = require('./build/contracts/Platform.json');
var platformContract = contract(platformArtifacts);
platformContract.setProvider(provider);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

function convertStringX(myString, len)
    {
    console.log("my String = " + myString);
    var myBuffer = [];
    var temp = Buffer.from(myString);

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
        // eliminate empty characters (different than spaces which are 0x20)
        if (i < myString.length)
            myBuffer.push(temp[i]);
        else
            myBuffer.push(0x0);         
        } 

    console.log(myBuffer);
    return myBuffer;
    }

var myPlatform;
const platformAddress = "0x...";

async function instantiatePlatform(deployedAddress) {
    myPlatform = await platformContract.at(deployedAddress);
    console.log("myPlatform address " + myPlatform.address);
    }

instantiatePlatform(platformAddress);

app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
});

var whitelist = ['localhost:8080']
var corsOptionsDelegate = function (req, callback) {
    var corsOptions;
    if (whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1) {
        corsOptions = { origin: true } // reflect (enable) the requested origin in the CORS response
    } else {
        corsOptions = { origin: false } // disable CORS for this request
    }
    callback(null, corsOptions) // callback expects two parameters: error and options
}

app.post('/deploy_client', (req, res) => {

    var insurerAddress = '0x...';
    var myClientUIC = req.body.clientUIC;
    myClientUIC = convertStringX(myClientUIC, 16);
    console.log("myClientUIC "+ myClientUIC);
    var myClientName = req.body.clientName;
    myClientName = convertStringX(myClientName, 16);
    console.log("myClientName "+ myClientName);
    var myClientGroup = req.body.clientGroup;
    myClientGroup = convertStringX(myClientGroup, 16);
    console.log("myClientGroup "+ myClientGroup);
    var myClientNACE = req.body.clientNACE;
    myClientNACE = convertStringX(myClientNACE, 3);
    console.log("myClientNACE "+ myClientNACE); 
    var myCreditLine = req.body.creditLine;
    console.log("myCreditLine "+ myCreditLine);
    var myCreditLineDate = req.body.creditLineDate;
    console.log("myCreditLineDate "+ myCreditLineDate);
    var myClientCurrency = req.body.clientCurrency;
    myClientCurrency = convertStringX(myClientCurrency, 3);
    console.log("myClientCurrency "+ myClientCurrency);
    var myClientCity = req.body.clientCity;
    myClientCity = convertStringX(myClientCity, 32);
    console.log("myClientCity "+ myClientCity);
    var myClientCountry = req.body.clientCountry;
    myClientCountry = convertStringX(myClientCity, 3);
    console.log("myClientCountry "+ myClientCountry);
    console.log("insurerAddress "+ insurerAddress);

    console.log("instance address " + myPlatform.address);

    myPlatform.createClient(myClientUIC, myClientName, myClientGroup, 
        myClientNACE, insurerAddress, myCreditLine, myCreditLineDate, myClientCurrency, myClientCity, myClientCountry,
        { from:provider.getAddress() })
        .once('transactionHash', function(hash) {
            console.log("TxHash: " + hash);
        }).on('receipt', function(receipt) { console.log("receipt: " + JSON.stringify(receipt)); })
            .then(function(result) {
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    });

const port = 80;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Anyone have any suggestions how to increase the speed of deployment?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you are using the default gas price. Did you try to explicitely set the gas price? When deploying in a public blockchain like ropsten or mainnet you are competing with everbody to have their transactions mined. A higher gas price will make your transactions to be prioritized over others.